# Error while posting data to server

Tags: angularjs

I want to hit a login API which will response username and password if login is successful otherwise it will return error but the problem is i am unable to send data to API.
this is my piece of code:

```
$scope.login=function(){
  $http.post("http://urbanholic.com/drago/index.php/api/users/login",
  {identity:$scope.data.identity, password:$scope.data.password})
   .then(function(response){
     $scope.responseMsg=response.data;
    },function(error){
     window.alert("error");
   });
  }
```

Comment: What's error you are getting while posting your data?

Comment: Please post the error you are getting. It will be easier to help

Comment: console is not showing any error but the problem is API is always returning the response which it should return only if i will enter a  wrong username or password..I am new in this filed kindly help

Comment: @user28: since API return response and not any error, then you need to check your backend code. logic

Comment: API is giving response that identity and password field is required(identity for username ). Which clearly states that there is an error in data posting. Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$scope.login=function(){
var data = $.param({
     identity:$scope.data.identity,
     password:$scope.data.password
        });

 $http.post("http://urbanholic.com/drago/index.php/api/users/login", data)
 .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.responseMsg=response.data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
             window.alert("error");
        });
 };
```

Comment: ionic.bundle.js:26799 ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at ChildScope.$scope.login (app.js:45)
    at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27643), <anonymous>:4:206)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65429
    at ChildScope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at ChildScope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30500)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65428)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16792)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16780)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2942)

Comment: i am getting the above mentioned error while using your code

Comment: Please add jquery file reference.